# Azure function note triggering from cron timer

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an azure function that is deployed in 3 places. Each one points at an asset and does its needed processing.

1 of the instances is not being triggered by the cron time set on it.

The other 2 work fine and trigger as per the schedule, the properties for them are all the same except the deviation of an asset id.

There are a total of 8 functions running (3 of this code base, the rest of another) within the resource group and 2 of those are HTTP Trigger functions.

They all run on Consumption models.

The code base for the function is C#

The SDK version is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.28)

Any ideas on why this one would cause issue?

EDIT:

Function.json

```
 {
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.28",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "schedule": "%cron-expression%",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/cpm-func-dev-processdata.dll",
  "entryPoint": "cpm_func_dev_processdata.cpmfuncdevprocessdata.Run"
}
```

Comment: which version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: The SDK version is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.28)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it is not triggered by cron. Do you pay attention to triggering according to UTC standard time by default? If it still triggers but does not follow the time you have given, then it is likely that you have not set a time zone.

Also, please note that the settings of local.settings.json are not uploaded to Azure with the deployment.

You need to add the time zone you want here:

[image]

[image]

Time zone table:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#time-zones.

Comment: It is set to run every minute, as stated there are 2 other deployments of the same code base that work correctly, it is just one of them that is not running.

Comment: @markblue777 Can you show the function.json of your function?

Comment: Sure i have put it in the edit, it is exactly the same as the other 2 instances that are working as expected.

Comment: @markblue777 If you use %%, the function will search for the corresponding string value in the environment variable. Did you add this setting in the Configuration?

Comment: yes I did, as i have said I have 2 other instances that work that have been setup the same and all configures align. It is deployed via a Devops release

Comment: @markblue777 Do you means it didn't be triggered at all?

Comment: Correct it does not trigger, It is like it has not been put on the scheduler. If i manually run it from the test window it runs fine

Comment: the cron is on a minute basis, looks like so 0 * * * * *

Comment: A note is that I published it to a different region (west europe) with the same config and it has been working fine since deployment. I currently have a different function that was running in the North Europe region that suddenly stopped running at 10:06 this morning (GMT) and has not triggered since